# Widevine classic - I get a server response error 16 (EMM decode failed)

Tags: android, drm, widevine

It started all of the sudden on one device and soon on all my devices and I can't seem to understand what this error even means or how to overcome this.

Comment: It sounds like your Proxy Server is corrupting the EMM message before sending it to Google.

Comment: I think it was due to a too big duration parameter and some devices didn't like it.